# Cypress When I click on Edit button, I no longer have access to cypress command

Tags: cypress

My test case have cy.click() in many places. I have no issue to continue and use cy.wait(300) or another other cypress functionality. However when I get to specific page, I no longer have access to any of the cy commands. I am not sure why this is happening. I have used many cypress commands. I have used cy.click many times. they all work. This is the only place that when I click on the edit or even if I just hardcode cy.visit(`editUrl`). I have no access to cy commands anymore.

[image]

```
cy.get('a[title="Locations"]').click();
    cy.wait(2000);
everything is normal till I get to here
so I click on Edit button
cy.get('.as-modal-disabled').contains('Edit').click() .. it finds Edit
but now if i use any cy function it will blow up
    cy.wait(3000); this could be cy.visit() .. any cy


I also tried this 
 cy.wait(6000);
    cy.get('.as-modal-disabled').contains('Edit', {timeout: 15000}).click()
again same issue anythign with cy after it blows up .

none of these commands works 
cy.get('#location_address_attributes_address1').click().clear()
    cy.get('#location_address_attributes_address1').type(randomAddress);
 I just get a red error
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you get ?

Comment: @AlapanDas it just kills the run and shows wait time in red. just like the image I posted. it stops cypress from running

Comment: Can you trying using `click({force: true})` ?

Comment: What does that do ?

Answer (score 0):

I am also currently have issues with this, the problem is edit elements are not available on the Dom in cypress chrome.

reproduction steps

1. run automation with cypress using any of the simple data, in my case
   I was using the shipping data on the shipping data page try clicking
   on the edit button. test will fail because it can not find locator.
   on a regular browser the locators are present but on cypress browser
   they can not be accessed.

@metawaa force click will not work because the elements are not on cypress chrome